# Which Machine Learning classification to use?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, text-classification

I have a  master dataset lets call it "train" with approx 7000 rows and 2 columns of text data. There is a column name "Item Description" with unique text description and another column called "Code" with unique values (see the below table). Please note the codes don't repeat and it is unique , also the "Item Description" will also be unique. Also the word count of the "Item Description" varies from short text to lengthy text .

Master Data  - I plan to use this full dataset as a training data

| Item Description | Code |
| --- | --- |
| I love cats | 000 |
| I love dogs and puppies | 001 |
| Dogs chase Cats | 002 |
| Cat chase Mouse | 003 |
| Dogs chase both mouse and cat | 004 |

I have another separate dataset lets call it "test" with 500 rows with Item Descriptions and codes and I need to check if the Item Description of the below table is mapped correctly using the above training master table as a reference. Please note this is not a text matching exercise, I need an ML / NLP  solution for matching

| Item Description | Code |
| --- | --- |
| dogs and puppies are cute | 000 |
| humans like cats | 001 |
| Cats run away from dogs | 002 |
| Rats dont like cats | 003 |
| Cats dont like mice | 004 |

- What type of classification does this fall  -  Multi Class Classification or Multilabel classification ?
- What similarity measures do I need to use ?
- How can I do a train test split - Is it possible since I have two separate dataset and each rows are unique in the master data ?

I am bit confused here... Please give me some tips to start this project and some useful weblinks for reference ?

I have done some coding but it is not working.

```
x_train=train['Item Description'].values
y_train = train['Code'].values

x_test = test['Item Description'].values
y_test = test['Code'].values
 
transformer = TfidfTransformer(smooth_idf=False)
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))

# fit train data to the count vectorizer
x_train = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(x_train)
y_train = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(y_train)


from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression(C=1e5)
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get

```
 ValueError: X has 25118 features, but LogisticRegression is expecting 26991 features as 
 input.
```

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

For the error please notice that the `X_train` used with `logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)` is not the same generated before in `x_train = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(x_train)`. You need to run:

```
logreg.fit(x_train, y_train)
```